# bootstrap 3 data-remote content on popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get to work a remote content for bootstrap 3 popover and I cant get the content to show.

My html:

```
<a class="btn-link mchat-link hidden-xs rule" href="javascript:void(0)" id="oneData" data-toggle="popover" title="{L__HELP}" data-remote="{T_SUPER_TEMPLATE_PATH}/the_rules.html" title="{L_HELP}" value="{L_HELP}"><i class="icon-moon-question"></i></a>
```

my js:

```
$('#oneData').popover({placement:'top', html:true});
```

what am I missing been trying this for hours and no success

Comment: What happens? Any errors in your console?

Comment: I've never heard of `data-remote` element being supported in bootstrap 3. Is that a new feature in an experimental build?

Comment: Correct there is no data-remote, but there is a data-content?

Comment: `data-content` doesn't accept URLs. Popovers have no `data-remote` option.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `data-remote` attribute for Bootstrap popover, but we can use it like this to load remote data into a Popover:

html

```
<a href="#" title="{your_title_here}" data-remote="{url_to_remote_php}">link</a>
```

js

```
$('*[data-remote]').on('mouseover', function() {
    var el = $(this);

    $.get(el.data('remote'),function(html) {
        el.popover({
            content: html,
            html : true,
            placement: 'right'
        });
        el.popover('show');
   });
});
```

I needed the popover to stay open until the user hovers out of the link or out of the popover so I added some magic to do just that

js (with stay open functionality)

```
$('*[data-remote]').on('mouseover', function() {
    var el = $(this);

    $.get(el.data('remote'),function(html) {
        el.popover({
            content: html,
            html : true,
            placement: 'right'
        });

        el.popover('show');

        $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function() {
            var el = $(this);
            el.popover('hide');
        });

        el.popover().on("mouseleave", function() {
            var el = $(this);
            setTimeout(function() {
                if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
                    el.popover("hide")
                }
            }, 300);
        });
    });
});
```